# Regex Replace "aaa.bbb.ccc" to "aaa/bbb/ccc.htm"

Tags: regex, replace, match

Original Text:

```
<tag keywords="testpage.page11" index="0">Good</tag>
```

Target Text:

```
<a href="testpage/page11.htm">Good</a>
```

How can I write the Regex?

What I have so far:

Match Expression: `<tag keywords=\"(.+?)\" index="\d+">(.*?)</tag>`

Replace Expression: `<a href="\1.htm">\2</a>`

but the problem is, how can I replace the `"testpage.page11"` to `"testpage/page11.htm"`?

How should I update my expressions?

The `"aaa.bbb.ccc"` part may also be `"abc.asd.dff.sssdf.sdfafda"` or `"a.b"`, the length of items or the number of items are not fixed.

Another thing is that I have to finish all the replace operations in one regex.

Comment: I don't see how it's possible to do all the replacements in one regex.

Comment: What language and/or utilities are you using to perform substitution using regular expressions?

Comment: You haven't mentioned the language in which you want to do this, but if it's PHP it's maybe worth looking at <a href="http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php">preg_replace</a> function.

Comment: You need two replacements in either case. One to perform the basic structural changes, the other to change `.` into `/`. You may put it into a single call by making the replacement a function call, but it will be two replacements anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Rexex you're looking to match is this:

```
/<tag keywords="([^"]+)" index="\d+">([^<]+)</tag>/
```

This obviously cannot be replaced in *single* replacement but you can use a function like `preg_replace_callback` to do this in one single function call.

Here I'm providing a PHP code to replace your original text:

```
$str = '<tag keywords="foo.bar.testpage.page11" index="0">Good</tag>';
$link = preg_replace_callback('#<tag keywords="([^"]+)" index="\d+">([^<]+)</tag>#i',
  create_function('$m',
    'return "<a href=\"" . str_replace(".", "/", $m[1]) . ".htm\">".$m[2]."</a>";'),
           $str);
echo $link . "\n";
```

#### OUTPUT

```
<a href="foo/bar/testpage/page11.htm">Good</a>
```

Comment: But this only works for a single dot->slash replacement. OP wants any number of dots to be replaced.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Yes I probably overlooked multiple `dot->slash` conversion requirement. Which obviously won't be possible in a single replacement call. Actual solution can be something along the line of preg_replace_callback.

Comment: Right. (It would be possible with .NET regexes (except for the "add .htm at the end" bit.)